# Print Table with List Variable From Entities in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I've not worked MVC for a long time; I'm a fresh guy to this. So, I have these two entities:

```
// Entity Worker

[Display(Name = "ID")]
public Int32 Id { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Número")]
public Int32 Numero { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Nome")]

// Entity Lottery

public Int32 Id { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Tipo")]
public String Tipo { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Data")]
public DateTime Data { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Observações")]
public List<Worker> FuncionariosSorteados { get; set; }
```

So, for each lottery entity, I will have a List of workers. I am passing the values to the View by the controller, like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Lottery lottery = service.FindLottery(id);
    if (sorteio == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(lottery);
}
```

Where the service is my Repository for the connection to database (in this case he do a search by ID on database to get the right lottery.

Here my doubt begin, if I want to do a table for the lotteries, I can do it doing (using Lottery model)

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tipo)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Observacoes)
            </tr>
    }
```

But how I can do the same for the `public List<Worker> FuncionariosSorteados`? I just want to print the `public List<Worker> FuncionariosSorteados` in a GridMvc table, but through the model I cant have access to it!

Comment: Define the model type as `Lottery` and use `Include()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to iterate through the list within the `foreach` loop you already created. Something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tipo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Observacoes)
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    @foreach(var w in Model.FuncionariosSorteados )
    {
      <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(w => w.Id)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(w => w.Numero)</td>
      </tr>
    }
  </table>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused because in your action, you're pulling a single lottery record and passing that to your view, but in your view, you're iterating through what appears to be an `IEnumerable<Lottery>`.

Since you'd have no issues accessing `FuncionariosSorteados` off of a `Model` of type `Lottery`, I'm assuming the view is actually using `IEnumerable<Lottery>`. For an enumerable, you have to iterate over the list and access the properties on the individual items. For example:

```
@model IEnumerable<Lottery>

@Model.FuncionariosSorteados <!-- fail -->

@foreach (var lottery in Model)
{
    @lottery.FuncionariosSorteados <!-- success -->
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your second entity you could create it like this:

```
Entitie Lottery        
public Lottery( )    
{       
  FuncionariosSorteados = new List <Worker>();   
  }     
public Int32 Id { get; set; }       
[Display(Name = "Tipo")]     
public    String Tipo { get; set; }     
[Display(Name = "Data")]    
public DateTime Data { get; set; }      
 [Display(Name = "Observações")]      
 public virtual List<Worker> FuncionariosSorteados { get; set; }
```

And thenin your view you can use a `foreach` loup to iterate inside the lists